# Is it possible to define a union type alias from an array of string literals in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

In TypeScript, I can do the following two things:

```
type ToolboxSpaceType = 'screw'|'hammer'|'screwdriver'; // 1

ProxyProperties = ['screw', 'hammer', 'screwdriver'];  // 2

class Toolbox {
  [key: ToolboxSpaceType]: ToolboxSpace;
}

let proxyHandler = {
  get(target: Toolbox, prop: PropertyKey, receiver: any) {
    if (ProxyProperties.include(prop) {
       //...do something special...
    }
  }
}
let personalToolbox = new Toolbox();
let personalToolboxProxy = new Proxy(personalToolbox, proxyHandler)
```

I'd like to be able to generate the `ToolboxSpaceType` from the `ProxyProperties` array of strings. Is there a way to do that in TypeScript?

Comment: My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45486495/2887218) is relevant; I'll flesh it out in an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Note: the code as presented in your post has problems and does not compile as written.  The following answer only concerns the first two lines involving the `ToolboxSpaceType` type and the `ProxyProperties` array, since that's what you are asking about.

---

You can do it.  It's best to add a helper function so your array will not be inferred as just `string[]`.  The following function forces the array element type to be inferred as a union of string literals:

```
function literalArray<K extends string>(args: K[]): K[] {
  return args;
}
```

Now ProxyProperties is inferred as `('screw'|'hammer'|'screwdriver')[]`:

```
const ProxyProperties = literalArray(['screw', 'hammer', 'screwdriver']);
```

and you can compute the union by extracting its element type:

```
type ToolboxSpaceType = typeof ProxyProperties[number];
```

---

In [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45486495/2887218) I recommended a helper function (`tuple()` in [tuple.ts](https://gist.github.com/jcalz/381562d282ebaa9b41217d1b31e2c211)) to infer tuple types, which might be even better for you, since `ProxyProperties` contains the literals exactly once in a known order. You'd use it like this:

```
const ProxyProperties = tuple('screw', 'hammer', 'screwdriver');  
//inferred as type ["screw", "hammer", "screwdriver"]

type ToolboxSpaceType = typeof ProxyProperties[number]; // still works
```

---

Hope that helps; good luck!