# Derive a type A from a list of strings a

Tags: list, typescript, converters

Say I have a constant and immutable list of strings `a`

```
const a = ['b', 'c', 'd']
```

and I want to create a type A that looks like this:

```
type A = 'b' | 'c' | 'd'
```

My question is: How do I create the type `A` from the list `a` automatically?

The other way around would work for me as well: How to create the list `a` given the type `A`

Comment: You cannot create types from runtime objects unless they are constants that cannot be modified like `const a = 'a'`.

Comment: It is my assumption that ```a``` is set constant and immutable. How do I create types from the list ```a```?

Comment: `a` is not immutable. You can do `a.push("x")` at runtime to modify the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you can do this.  The only barrier is that if you write

```
const a = ['b','c','d'];
// inferred as string[]
```

then `a` will be inferred as `string[]`, so the literal values `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'` are forgotten by the time you try to derive `A`.  You can always annotate the type of `a` explicitly:

```
const a: ['b','c','d'] = ['b','c','d'];
type A = typeof a[number];
//type A = "b" | "c" | "d"
```

but now you are repeating yourself, which you are trying to avoid.  There is a solution:

---

In [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45486495/2887218) I recommended a helper function (`tuple()` in [tuple.ts](https://gist.github.com/jcalz/381562d282ebaa9b41217d1b31e2c211)) to infer tuple types.

```
const a = tuple('b','c','d');
//inferred as type ["b", "c", "d"]

type A = typeof a[number]; 
//type A = "b" | "c" | "d"
```

If you don't care about it being a tuple, you can write a simple array inference helper function instead:

```
function inferLiteralArray<T extends string>(...arr: T[]): T[] {
  return arr;
}

const a = inferLiteralArray("b", "c", "d");
//inferred as type ("b" | "c" | "d")[]

type A = typeof a[number];
//type A = "b" | "c" | "d"
```

Either way works, and you don't need to repeat yourself.  Hope that helps; good luck!

---

#### Update 1

@fritz_da_silva [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445115/derive-a-type-a-from-a-list-of-strings-a/46448445?noredirect=1#comment79855021_46448445):

> awesome, it works neatly!!! the a[number] syntax looks like black magic to me. could u please elaborate on why it works?

Sure.  The syntax should be interpreted like this (see the parentheses I added for clarity):

```
type A = (typeof a)[number];
```

The `typeof a` part is using the [`typeof` type query operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.8.10) to get the type of `a`, which (for the `tuple()` example) is `["b", "c", "d"]`.

Then I am using the [indexed access operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types).  If you have a type `T` and a type `K` of one of its *keys* (so it should extend `keyof T`; you can use string literals like `"length"` or numeric literals like `0` or unions of these), then `T[K]` is the type of the property accessible at that key.  For an arraylike type `A`, the type `A[number]` gets the type of the elements of that array type.  In the tuple example, this turns out to be a union, because there are multiple keys of type `number` with different property types.  (When you use the indexed access operator, `T[K1|K2]` should be equal to `T[K1]|T[K2]`).  Observe:

```
type TheTuple = typeof a; // ['b','c','d'];
type Zeroth = TheTuple[0]; // 'b'
type First = TheTuple[1]; // 'c'
type Second = TheTuple[2]; // 'd'
type A = TheTuple[number]; // 'b'|'c'|'d'
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: awesome, it works neatly!!! the a[number] syntax looks like black magic to me. could u please elaborate on why it works?

Comment: See Update 1 above

Comment: You're welcome.  If you think this answer has helped you, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible as the array is created at runtime, and changes to the array cannot be determined by the compiler. Therefore, it cannot enforce a type system.

For example, consider the following:

```
const array = [ "Bob", "James", "Dan" ];
let value: *A key of array*
setTimeout(() => {
    value = "James";
}, 1000);
array.splice(1, 1);
```

What would happen in the above scenario? By the time `value = "James` is called, `"James"` has been removed from the array, so an error should be thrown! But this occurs at runtime so the compiler is unable to warn you.

The workaround is to declare a type with the following construct, however it cannot be modified:

```
type MyType = "Bob" | "James" | "Dan"
let value: MyType = "Dan";
value = "Steven" // <- Compiler error!
```

EDIT: [saravana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445115/derive-a-type-a-from-a-list-of-strings-a/46445643#comment79846695_46445115) sums it up quickly in their comment.