# Why does tuple inference from any[] become [string, string, ... ] and from string[] become ['literal1', 'literal2', ... ]

Tags: typescript, tuples, type-inference

I have read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45486495/1108891, which demonstrates tuple type inference. After some experimentation, I came across this scenario.

---

When our `tuple` function has `T extends string[]`, the tuple has **string literal** types.

```
export const tuple_0 = <T extends string[]>(...args: T): T => args;

const ALL_SUITS_0 = tuple_0('hearts', 'diamonds', 'spades', 'clubs');

type T0 = typeof ALL_SUITS_0; // ["hearts", "diamonds", "spades", "clubs"]
```

On the other hand, with `T extends any[]`, the tuple has **string** types (not literals).

```
export const tuple_1 = <T extends any[]>(...args: T) => args;

const ALL_SUITS_1 = tuple_1('hearts', 'diamonds', 'spades', 'clubs');

type T1 = typeof ALL_SUITS_1; // [string, string, string, string]
```

Why do we lose the literal types in the latter case?

---

I suspect this has something to do with how many specificity steps the type inferences allows itself to take. That is, `any` is one step away from `string`, and `string` is one step away from `'some-string-literal'`. Does the type inference only allow itself to take one step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not specific to tuples necesarily. Typescript will infer a literal type for a generic parameter if the type parameter has a constraint that can have literal types. This behavior was introduced by this [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676)

From the PR:

> During type argument inference for a call expression the type inferred for a type parameter T is widened to its widened literal type if [...] `T` has no constraint or its constraint does not include primitive or literal types

In the example from your question, since `string` is primitive, we do not widen, and since `any` is not primitive, we do widen.

Comment: So it is that the `any` type can be a non-literal, such as a `Date`, and so TypeScript literal inference does not apply?

Comment: When you write, " ...has a constraint that can have literal types," do you mean "... has a constraint that must have literal types"? I ask because it seems that `extends any` can have literal types.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Yes. `any` can be anything so `T` will be not be inferred to a literal type (or as the PR describes it, it will be widened to the non literal type).

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I'm not sure how to phrase it exactly, to infer a lietrral type the constraint has to be `string`, `number` `boolean` or an enum.

Comment: I see it also has something to do with mutability. For instance: `ALL_SUITS_0[0] = 'foo';` fails whereas `ALL_SUITS_1[0] = 'foo';` succeeds.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin you can assign a value to `ALL_SUITS_0[0] = 'foo'` it just always has to be `'hearts'`. It's not immutable in a true sense, there is just one value you can assign

Comment: @ShaunLuttin added the quote, feel free to add any other infor from the PR you find relevant :)