# Extract string union from array of objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have following object

```
[{
    "key": "a1",
    ...
}, {
    "key": "a2",
    ...
}, ...]
```

Is it possible to extract union type `"a1" | "a2" | ...` from this object?
I am aware that it is possible to extract it from `['a1', 'a2', ...]` by using tuple API, which was presented here [TypeScript String Union to String Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480644/typescript-string-union-to-string-array), but I can't figure it out for object array

Answer (score 7):

Basically you just want to do a [lookup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) of the `"key"` property of the elements of the array, where the elements of an array can be found by looking up its `number` property.  Unfortunately, the hard part is getting that to show up as anything but `"string"`.

```
const val = [{ key: "a1" }, { key: "a2" }]; // Array<{key: string}>
type ValueAtKey = (typeof val)[number]["key"]; // string
```

That's because the compiler infers `val` to just be an array of objects with a `string` value.  The compiler uses some heuristics to determine [when to widen literals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676), and in the above case, the exact string literals have been widened to `string`.

**UPDATE FOR TS3.4+**

As of TypeScript 3.4, the recommended way to make the compiler infer the most specific type for an object/array literal is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const val = [{ key: "a1" }, { key: "a2" }] as const;
// const val: readonly [{  readonly key: "a1"; }, { readonly key: "a2"; }] 
type ValueAtKey = (typeof val)[number]["key"]; // "a1" | "a2"
```

**ORIGINAL PRE-TS3.4 ANSWER**

Before TS3.4, you had to do something else.  One of the ways to hint to the compiler that a value like `"a1"` should stay narrowed to `"a1"` instead of widened to `string` is to have the value match a type [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `string` (or a union containing it).  The following is a helper function I sometimes use to do this:

```
type Narrowable = 
  string | number | boolean | symbol | object | 
  null | undefined | void | ((...args: any[]) => any) | {};

const literally = <T extends { [k: string]: V | T } | Array<{ [k: string]: V | T }>,
  V extends Narrowable>(t: T) => t;
```

The `literally()` function just returns its argument, but the type tends to be narrower. Yes, it's ugly.

Now you can do:

```
const val = literally([{ key: "a1" }, { key: "a2" }]); // Array<{key: "a1"}|{key: "a2"}>
type ValueAtKey = (typeof val)[number]["key"]; // "a1" | "a2"
```

The `val` object is the same at runtime, but the TypeScript compiler now sees it as an array of values of type `{key: "a1"}` or `{key: "a2"}`.  Then the lookup done for `ValueAtKey` gives you the union type you're looking for.

(Note that I assume you don't care about the ordering of `val` here.  That is, you are fine treating it as an array instead of as a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple).  Since the union type `"a1" | "a2"` doesn't have an inherent ordering, then the array should be sufficient.)

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAOSgdxQb2CglRAexBgBcUA3MAGxQF4UBtHFAaygE8AuFAIjABGfigC+AGlwdufQQCZRYgLoowMIqQoBufIQD0+zWUo1afAE5QwAE1K0uLNiiu37jzrwHD+28VLZXOxAHGS8FX3FVPQJyLjhUADU6AFcoAEFyAGluRhQACjiE4gAzajoASmYQFIgAIygLZWZ+T35lP0NvERQAH29FFEBeDcAhPeBgMXHQSFgEZBQAeVobXBiUItQ0MAsLYkwwOtpUBjXCFAoLAEsQAHM+lBr6xvu64mIjsBB7mC569-viHUAFZQRCUXqnQg1Wj0fopEA2KAla5QFb9KjES5ogr5AB0+O2NxgfE+XGYygqjAAfGoQFxKf0cGJdGsSCYULRLuRGnRQkwADwAFRQUAAHtyERo2Mx2HwLtcbso+Il7sKxPd0jswFx+dLZedyFdbkqUCr+mqqRJIQQVWKJTYNFsdnsDkcqYU+ILKQwaeQWWc2RRyvQmJzuRZeVx8qwwnIfP5pJ444MVBVOkZNRGdTgk91+GJejnZAN81S1htTakMtlckxCvEoKVg1VHg0mi02h0UF1BD1+hFhmMJkA)

Comment: Hi @jcalz thanks for the answer! I've a follow up question. if `literally` takes a reference of a variable instead of a value, Typescript takes to narrowing again. 

`
const val = [{ key: "a1" }, { key: "a2" }]; // Array<{key: string}>
const val1 = literally(val);
type ValueAtKey1 = (typeof val1)[number]["key"]; // "string" 
`

is there something one can do here?

Comment: Hi @jcalz! I just stumbled upon my own question, here in the comments, after 6 months  and realised I still don't know how to do that. Could you help me out?

Comment: There's no way to retrieve such information once the compiler has already thrown it away by widening; you need to prevent the widening in the first place.  The way to prevent widening is shown in this answer (updated now to show `const` assertions).  If that was not prevented, there's not much you can do.  Note that a follow-up question in a comment on a year-old answer is not the best place to get attention; if you have a question and you can't find an answer for it, you might want to make your own post asking it.

Comment: Understood, thank you for the answer, and thank you for also pointing out that making a new question, if not duplicate, would have been a better place to ask. Appreciate it.