# How do I type the values of an object's fields with a specific subset of keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I have an object containing multiple types of values:

```
interface Foo {
  id: number;
  data: FooData;
  username: string;
  notes: string;
}

const foo: Foo = {
  ...
}
```

I have a function that requires a string, and am iterating through a specific list of fields in my object to use in that function, all of which contain string values:

```
const renderString = (value: string) => {
  ...
}

const fooKeys: keyof Foo = ["username", "notes"];

fooKeys.map((key) => {
  renderString(foo[key])
}
```

The issue is that `foo[key]` can be a `string`, `number`, or `FooData` object, so I want to specify that `foo[key]` will ONLY be a field value of `Foo` with a key matching one in `fooKeys`, since they are all going to be string values.

We can assert `foo[key] as string` but that doesn't protect us against bad keys in fooKeys.

Comment: Why not just `const fooKeys = ["username", "notes"] as const;` and forget `keyof Foo` at all?  (and it would be `Array<keyof Foo>` anyway, not just `keyof Foo`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a conditional type to only allow `string` properties since that appears to be the only ones allowed? For example:

```js
type StringPropsOnly<T> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends string ? Key : never;
}[keyof T]

const fooKeys: StringPropsOnly<Foo>[] = ["username", "notes"];

fooKeys.map((key) => {
  renderString(foo[key])
});
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0BE5jsgbwChlkZMc8AuZAZzClAHMBuIgXyKNElkRQzpCJZMAAmNEAFcAtgCNobUmNxwagynCXIptaCDgyINeoxCsRIdJFomGzNpyIJ0IemUzrMyALzDSAPQByAB0YRxcLm5gyFAQIGLQAMr25r7IABQAbnAANlLGdKlMAJS+AHz+yEGkYSERRGAAngAOKClmTAAKUOgttADyILlNADwAKpV+xKQA2gDSEE2iIMgA1kvoMMjjALo04wtLu8gQAB6QCbRFncgA-MiLy5IQWYocsxtNWzu7ka7ucjoJ62ZAdZg9PqDYZjQTlWYnPyzABEun0hggyIANMhkVYbMjdmwiECQSEZHAWhkMl8yj5KjNYvFElBweYMkDPscShwSiwgA)

Answer (score 1):

[This answer I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480644/typescript-string-union-to-string-array) mentions `as const`:

```
const fooKeys = ["username", "notes"] as const;
```

Comment: This could be a nice solution, but isn't scalable, and is prone to breaking changes, since it doesn't have any link to `Foo`. @skovy's solution is the best once - gets all `string`-typed property names of `Foo`, and whenever such are added - will support them.

Comment: @AmitB.: As long as some use like the `fooKeys.map` exists, it will produce an error there, which could be good enough for such an easy solution.