# Is it possible to get array of keys from a string literal type

Tags: typescript

I'm using a 3rd party library that has defined a type like this:

```
type DefaultButtons = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F' | 'G' | 'H';
```

there is a function that I can call that lets me remove buttons, and it has an api that looks like this:

```
removeDefaultButtons( buttonsToRemove : DefaultButtons[] );
```

In my code I know that I would like to keep (say) 'A', 'D' and 'G' but remove all the rest.

Therefore, I'd like to do something like this:

```
const buttonsToKeep : DefaultButtons[] = ['A', 'D', 'G'];

const allPossibleButtons : DefaultButtons[] = ?? //how to populate this

const removeButtons = allPossibleButtons.filter( b => buttonsToKeep.includes( b ) );
removeDefaultButtons( removeButtons );
```

The problem is that I'm not sure how I can populate the allPossibleButtons array from the string literal type?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480644/typescript-string-union-to-string-array does not answer my question.  In that question the poster wants to convert an array to a type.  I want the complete opposite.  I have a type, but want to get an array.

Comment: Doesn't the `getAllStringUnionValues` function from the question poster code in the linked post do, what you are trying to achieve (string literal union type  -> tuple)?

Comment: If I'm understanding the getAllStringUnionValues function, it looks like that function needs to be called by passing in an object containing the keys that match a particular type. I don't even have such an object in my case.  All I have is a string literal type defined for DefaultButtons.  I want to be able to extract all the strings from this type, and put them in an array.

Comment: Yeah, you would have to create the object literal from the type constraint manually so that it is also existent at run-time, as types get lost after compilation. I think, that is the general way to go here (was about to post an answer similar to the linked OP question code).

Comment: The question this duplicates specifically asks for a way to take a type and generate an array from it, like you're asking.  The answer is that you can't do that, the type system is erased.  Instead, you can do the reverse: make an array and generate your type from it.  If that doesn't suit your needs, then there's not much to say; you can't generate runtime code from types.