# How to iterate typescript string literal?

Tags: typescript

I have this literal type `export type names = 'n1' | 'n2' | 'n3' | 'n4' | 'n5' | 'n6';`

I wonder how would you iterate that type ?

May be you can convert that type in something else and iterate that?

Should you redefine the type in a different way?

```
names.forEach(value => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean, "iterate type"? A type does not exist in the compiled Javascript

Comment: I don't think you can enumerate the types in a type declaration like that; you could change it to a string enum though, and then you should be able to enumerate the values.

Comment: @DaveCousineau do you have a sample?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript String Union to String Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480644/typescript-string-union-to-string-array).  You should define the `names` array first and have the compiler infer the `names` type from it, not the other way around (which is not possible)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Short Answer

You could define it as a const and a type like this:

```
const names = ['n1' , 'n2' , 'n3' , 'n4' , 'n5' , 'n6'] as const;

// This produces the union type 'n1' | 'n2' | 'n3' | 'n4' | 'n5' | 'n6';
type names = typeof names[number];

// use names as a type here
const n1: names = 'n1';

console.log({
  names,
  n1,
  // use names as an array here
  mapped: names.map(name => `I am ${name}`)
});
```

## Explanation and Demo

What is going on here?

The `as const` creates an array with a [const context](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions). That means the array is not a `string` array but is a readonly array of specific string literal values.

Then, the `typeof names[number]` uses an [indexed access operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) to extract those string literal values into a union type.

If we did not use `as const` to define our array, then the `typeof names[number]` would give us `string` type instead of a union of the array's string literal values.

The end result is pretty neat. We can use `names` as a union type for type checking and as an array at runtime.

Here it [is in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCGBbAphGBeGBtA5GAjDjADQx4BMRpeAzFWWACz14CsLYAbDgLozxpQkKAG4AUGID0kmABUAFgEs0ABwBOIACYBXYKhhR5yAwE8Vx7WEXgGhGAB8GlBwzou8zd2HZfu4qGbGCChomAHmIABmcEioWGDaiABGyGo84mJC0HD4AFwxIRi2OBlZIAA2yAB05SAA5gAUAN5iMAWoxK05nW2I8CrmmvnBqFV9Kg0jGAB8MAAGAJL8iDAAJE0jAL5zAJRimzsiQA), and here is the playground output in JavaScript:

```js
"use strict";
const names = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n6'];
const n1 = 'n1';
console.log({
names,
n1,
mapped: names.map(name => `I am ${name}`)
});
```

Caveat: The use of `names` as both a union type an an array value raises a question about naming conventions. Usually types are PascalCased (e.g. `Names`) and values are camelCased (e.g. `names`). Which naming conventions ought we to follow here?

For completeness, here is how it looks in VS Code across two files:

[image]

Comment: why do you need this line `type names = typeof names[number];` ?

Comment: @sreginogemoh the `typeof names[number]` uses an indexed access operator to get the string literal types of the array values.

Comment: seems like there is something wrong with `names.forEach(name => name)` if you check the playground url it output `Array(6) [ "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n5", "n6" ]
 n1 undefined`

Comment: @sreginogemoh Nice catch. Fixed.

Comment: @sreginogemoh `const names` and `type names` have the same name, because I read your requirements as 1. define a string literal type and 2. enable iterating over that string literal "type". We did that by giving `const names` and `type names` the same name. That way we fulfill (1) by creating a type, and we fulfill (2) by creating a value *with the same name* as the type.

Comment: if I have my literals in separate files I had to export `type names`, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210708/discussion-between-shaun-luttin-and-sreginogemoh).

Comment: hey, there are you still in the chat?

Answer (score 3):

Types do not exist in the compiled code - there is nothing emitted to iterate over.

If you need the union type as shown in the question *and* need to be able to iterate over it as an array, first create the array `as const`, and define the type as the array's values:

```
const arr = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n6'] as const;
export type names = typeof arr[number];
for (const num of arr) {
  console.log(num);
}
```

Comment: why do you need this like `export type names = typeof arr[number];` ?

Comment: `typeof arr[number]` will give you the type of accessing a `number` property on the `arr` - eg `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, etc, and those accesses result in a value of `'n1'`, or `'n2'`, etc - it creates a union type of all values in the array.

Comment: i just removed `export type names = typeof arr[number];` seems like `for` loop still works...

Comment: If you don't actually need the type union described in the question, then feel free to remove it