# Create value array from a union of strings

Tags: typescript

How can I convert a type union into an array of values?

I'm trying to create this:

```
const sportsArray = ['Football', 'Baseball', 'Hockey'];
```

...from this:

```
type Sports = 'Football' | 'Baseball' | 'Hockey';
```

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480644/typescript-string-union-to-string-array

Comment: The answer to that question is a bit confusing to me, as it seems like it's going from array -> type, whereas I'm trying to go from type -> array

Comment: The answer linked by @Abhilash states it is not possible to do what you are trying to accomplish. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298 proposal was declined as it would not leave the type system fully erasable.