# Exhaustive type check on arrays in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typechecking

I'm trying to create an exhaustive typecheck for an array from a type alias.

```js
type Elevation = '1' | '2' | '3';

type SomeExhaustiveType = ???

const elevationArray: SomeExhaustiveType<Elevation>[] = ['1', '2']; // <-- show error here because 3 is not in the array
```

Is it possible to check if all members of `type Elevation` are in `elevationArray`?

Comment: care to share the typescript version?

Comment: I'm not getting an error https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-pjsch1?file=Hello.tsx

Comment: It is correct; no errors : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAogNhAbgQ2ASwPYDsoF4oDkAjAVAD6EBMpFBAzAQNwBQzAxtgM7BQQIrpsAQQBOI5CABcsfqkxYA2gF08UBcQIAaKgSWMgA

Comment: it won't show errors because elevationArray does not contain invalid members of Elevation type. However, I want to check that all members of `type Elevation` are in `elevationArray`. I'm sorry I wrote the question in a misleading way.

Comment: Why not generate the union *from* an exhaustive array/tuple of values? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480644/typescript-string-union-to-string-array

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you, that's what I was looking for! If you want I'll mark it as the answer, just post it below.