# Typescript: DRY definition of string union and full array with the same item type

Tags: arrays, typescript, union

As shown elsewhere (e.g. [TypeScript String Union to String Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480644/typescript-string-union-to-string-array)) it is easy to define union type from tuple:

```js
const arr = ["foo", "bar"] as const
const Item = typeof arr[number]
```

Unfortunately I cannot use `arr` where `Item[]` is required - the type of `arr` is `readonly ["foo", "bar"]`, and even direct type cast results in typescript error TS2352.

Typescripts suggests to cast to `unknown` first - it works but it looks confusing and kind of defeats the whole purpose of type-safe array constant:

```js
const _arr: Item[] = (arr as unknown) as Item[]
```

Is there any better way to have both the full list of options as `Item[]` and `Item` union type without repeating the actual options, other than above double cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is *type-unsafe*. Given

```
const arr = ["foo", "bar"] as const
```

If you could type the same `arr` as `Item[]` when using it somewhere, and then (for example) pass it to a function which accepts `Item[]` as a parameter, that function could then do:

```
arrayParameter.push('foo');
```

which would be perfectly fine because the parameter would still remain an `Item[]`. But the original type is now incorrect, because the mutated `arr` is no longer `["foo", "bar"] as const` - rather, it has 3 items.

Slice (or otherwise somehow shallow copy) the array first if you want to use it as a generic `Item[]`. There's no other way to do this which would be type-safe.

```
const arr = ['foo', 'bar'] as const;
type Item = typeof arr[number];
const arrItems: Item[] = arr.slice();
```

Answer (score 1):

if your function takes `readonly string[]` this as input, then you can pass existing arr, I know you might not have a control or change the function signature, but just throwing this out in case it helps

```js
const tuple = ['foo', 'bar'] as const


function println(arr: readonly string[]) {
  console.log(arr)
}

println(tuple)
println(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```