# How to get the keys of a typescript defined type?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to extract the "keys" of a type like i would do with an object and save use them (storing in a variable, mapping, etc)?

consider the object variant:

```
const obj = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c' };
const objWithKeys = Object.keys(obj); 
console.log(objWithKeys); // console output: ['0', '1', '2']
```

can i do the same *somehow* for a type and then use those keys for something like a dropdown menu?

```
type scheme = "dhcp" | "static";
const schemeItems = Object.keys(scheme); 
const console.log(schemeItems); // would like to have ["dhcp","static"]
```

Is this somehow possible to get the desired results and if not why and what should you do instead?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480644/string-union-to-string-array/45486495#45486495

Comment: You can only derive a type from a value, not the other way around: `const SCHEME = ["dhcp", "static"] as const; type Scheme = typeof SCHEME[number]`

Comment: @AlekseyL. seems right to me but can you explain why you added [number] to the typeof SCHEME assignment?

Comment: `[number]` is needed to query the tuple's item type (to get the union of all values)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

It is impossible to do in TypeScript, since `type` scope and `variables` scope are different scopes.

You can even define same name for variable and type and it will work perfectly fine

```
type age=number;
const age = 'efr'.
```

Comment: Any type can not be used in console log

Comment: thanks for your reply. 
Your example works fine but its not what i intended to do.
I wanted to extract the keys of the type, like storing it in a variable and use it for items in a dropdown menu. (Edited my question)