# Array of Classes to Union (or vice verca)

Tags: typescript, types, union

The thing I'm trying to achieve is repeating myself less and have less bug-potential.

I need the following (yes I need both):

```js
const unionTypes = [GQLDualTaskState, GQLNumericTaskState];
type UnionType = GQLDualTaskState | GQLNumericTaskState;
```

As you can see I have to repeat the classes and change always both (e.g. adding or removing a class).

I searched quite a bit to find a solution by myself but didn't.
This seem to work with strings only: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45486495/1469540

The step I'm currently at is:

```js
type UnionTypeDef = [GQLDualTaskState, GQLNumericTaskState];
const unionTypes = [GQLDualTaskState, GQLNumericTaskState];
type UnionType = UnionTypeDef[number];
```

I understand that the syntax `Class['property']` returns the type of the property `property` of the class `Class`. But why is the result of `UnionTypeDef[number]` a Union?

Summarized there are two questions:

1. How do I solve the problem of having a list of classes and a union of the same classes (and I want to understand the solution)?
2. Why is the result of `UnionTypeDef[number]` a Union?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the result of `UnionTypeDef[number]` a Union?

Why wouldn't it be?

See the following comments explaining exactly what happening here.

```
class A { a: string = 'a' }
class B { b: string = 'b' }

// This is a type. It is tuple with a length of 2.
// index 0: a class A instance
// index 1: a class B instance
type UnionTypeDef = [A, B];

// This is a value. It is an array with a length of 2.
// index 0: the class A constructor
// index 1: the class B constructor
const unionTypes = [A, B];

// When you index an array or tuple by `number` you get a union of all possible
// values of all indices. In this case, `A | B`.
type UnionType = UnionTypeDef[number];
```

---

> How do I solve the problem of having a list of classes and a union of the same classes?

First of all, you say these are classes. So that would means that `const unionTypes` are the class constructors, and you would use `type UnionType` for instances?

If so, you want to start with a constant tuple `[A, B, C]` rather than the type. This is because types do not exist at runtime, so you can't create a value from a type, but you can generate a type from a value.

```
class A { a: string = 'a' }
class B { b: string = 'b' }
class C { c: string = 'c' }

const arrayOfConstructors = [A, B]; // only include A, and B

// Solution:
type UnionType = InstanceType<(typeof arrayOfConstructors)[number]>;

// UnionType can be instance of A or B
const instanceOfA: UnionType = new A()
const instanceOfB: UnionType = new B()
const instanceOfC: UnionType = new C() // Error: Type 'C' is not assignable to type 'A | B'.
```

Here's how that works:

```
typeof arrayOfConstructors
```

In order to get a type from a value, you need to use the [`typeof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#the-typeof-type-operator). This brings it into type land.

```
(typeof arrayOfConstructors)[number]
```

To get a union of all possible members of an array or tuple, you index it by number. All possible values for all numeric keys are returned as a union. i.e. `['a', 'b'][number] //=> 'a' | 'b'`

```
InstanceType<SomeClass>
```

When using a class as a type, typescript assumes you mean the type for instances of this class. If you mean the class constructor, then you use `typeof MyClass` instead.

So `const arrayOfConstructors = [A, B]` creates an array of class constructors, not instances. Which means the type of that value would actually be `[typeof A, typeof B]`. [`InstanceType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) gets the type of instances from a class type.

For example: (a very contrived example)

```
type ABInstances = InstanceType<typeof A | typeof B> // type is A | B
```

All that means that, since you have a union of class constructors, you need to get the instance types from them.

---

If you use the pattern a lot, you can refactor it to something like:

```
interface Constructable { new(...args: any[]): any }
type InstanceUnion<T extends Constructable[]> = InstanceType<T[number]>
```

The `Constructable` type represents any class constructor. It defined so that it can be used a constraint in the `InstanceUnion`, thereby throwing type errors you you try to pass it a string or plain object.

The `InstanceUnion` type accepts an array or tuple of class constructors, gets the union of its values, and then gets the `InstanceType` of all members of that union.

Now you can just:

```
type UnionType = InstanceUnion<typeof arrayOfConstructors>;
type OtherUnionType = InstanceUnion<typeof otherArrayOfConstructors>;
```

[Playground with working examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9pgFzQgFwE4EsB2A5tALzQDkYZ0AvgFCiQwBCi0ARmproSeW1XQZRoAYVbBO2fEVJlgA2rXwYAplgBmYYCtEB7PFwCuwDGDYgdSPCoDuACgB0TsFgIQ0YPAE8A2gF0ASg9vGloMLwAHHQBJA1M8bQBVPBx9AB4AFWgVAA9VPAATGBF9IxMzC38APl5YzE9tDMiVTJ88QwBbNjU-KsVgUoxkLCwwLwB5dRK4rGMMXSwYUh9YABpoJj8AbmgAel3ofRAvaHxQQwKdNeRCjYdoaPVoL11DZAKC0WgACzUVdYwv2yIwW7BUIF0NnQ31eIE+BF0yBsYwcYWa0GSqTwTSitTiDRUmPS4SiuieLlGEymg1mJgWECqW0U+wxKX0OJ0wE8YNO+ISOjJcEOWA29EGvPq-MmsDQROx6NI1ihsDsATFcQl8W0kyYsrZ8txitsG1V6swmoJkxEeqxHN4StEqr2BwAoiCsGg7WQRFQcDA8LohowcAQ8BUdPNoCSdGR4AAfDZkBxAA)

Comment: Thank you so much :) `InstanceType` was the missing piece. And thank you for explaining the result. It helped me a lot in understanding TS better. I'm coming from Java/Kotlin and therefore have some "understanding" difficulties with the TS-typesystem. Do you have any link for me to learn the typesystem in more detail (deep-dive)?

Comment: The official typescript handbook is good: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html The rest just comes with experience (and lots of googling)