# Typescript extract keys from object to obtain readonly array

Tags: typescript

I have an array of the form

```
const arr = [
  { foo: 'a' },
  { foo: 'b' },
  ...
] as const;
```

One thing this lets me do is generate the union type `'a' | 'b' | ...` with `typeof arr[number]['foo']`. However, if I want to get the array form of the union type (like [String Union to string Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480644/string-union-to-string-array)), there doesn't seem to be a good solution.

```
arr.map(({foo}) => foo)
```

is of type `('a' | 'b' | ...)[]` instead of `readonly ['a', 'b', ...]`. How can I get the latter?

Comment: I guess it would be something like [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gKBjA3jAMxBAC4YByOcmAXwBps9DizyAja+zAXXghlCQoAbkyYoATwAOAUxgBBJKhiTZIAvCSjVcgGLEA8gQA8AFQB8y0zBkAPKDLAATfviKkYASzAEZyAGq0MAD8MIFkYDIAbn7a0nrEishoSTb2ji5ePn4KIUzoANJZMADWMhLqCtxk+iBGxkmF3JY0MBHRsZhAA)?

Comment: ...or [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gKBjA3jAMxBAC4YByOcmAXwBps9DizyAja+zAXXghlCQoAbkyYoATwAOAUxgAxYgHkCAHgAqAPlQx1MGQA8oMsABN++IqRgBLMARnIAarRgB+GC7JgZAN0eikrIKxACCSKoAkqH6RibmMAgycKbgADYSTFZkAK5gANZgIADuYLTo3Npo0bHGZvx2DsgxHvjoANK2ZfkyEiAEMKHcZIogKqqhHZWu3n4B4tJySjlQUis6o+EIqkEy-fBImphAA) , which is a bit more type-safe imo.

Comment: wow! now I'm curious, is it possible to actually generate an array that would have this type without typecasting?

Comment: No, and that is by design. Mapping over an array returns a _new_ array, and TypeScript can't (and shouldn't) assume that the new array should _also_ be readonly. You have to cast it so explicitly. It can only infer what types will be in the array, not their ordinality or readonly status. That said, casting is fine if you are careful about it; it exists pretty much for scenarios like this among others.