# How to exhaustive check the elements in an array in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Given that I can use a `Record` to make me not forget to type all options in an object

```js
type Country = "uk" | "france" | "india";

export const data: Record<Country, boolean> = {
  uk: true,
  france: true,
  // complains that india is not present, excellent!
};
```

how can I make so it complains the same way for arrays?

```js
export const data = [
  {value: "uk"},
  {value: "france"},
  // how to make typescript complain here that I forgot to add {value: "india"}?
];
```

Comment: There is no proper type which would do this validation for you. You could create a union of all possible array combinations or just settle for one particular order of elements. Alternatively, you could use a generic function to which you would pass the array. The generic function could use inference and a generic type to do this check at compile time.

Comment: If you cannot supply duplicates, then it is possible to create a type that represents all permutations (which may be inefficient and taxing on the compiler if your union has a few more members). Otherwise, you'll need a utility helper function.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70327789/10000528), I think that this solves your problem:

```
type Country = "uk" | "france" | "india";

type MapOfKeysOf<U extends string> = {
    [key in U]: MapOfKeysOf<Exclude<U, key>>;
}

type ExhaustiveArrayOfObjects<Keys extends {[key: string]: {}}, T = {}, KeyName extends string = "value"> = {} extends Keys ? [] : {
    [key in keyof Keys]: [T & Record<KeyName, key>, ...ExhaustiveArrayOfObjects<Keys[key], T, KeyName>];
}[keyof Keys]

export const data: ExhaustiveArrayOfObjects<MapOfKeysOf<Country>> = [
    {
        value: 'uk',
    },
    {
        value: 'france',
    },
    {
        value: 'india',
    }
]
```

If you want, you can pass an extra type to extends or event customize the prop that will hold de value

```
type Country = "uk" | "france" | "india";

type MapOfKeysOf<U extends string> = {
    [key in U]: MapOfKeysOf<Exclude<U, key>>;
}

type ExhaustiveArrayOfObjects<Keys extends {[key: string]: {}}, T = {}, KeyName extends string = "value"> = {} extends Keys ? [] : {
    [key in keyof Keys]: [T & Record<KeyName, key>, ...ExhaustiveArrayOfObjects<Keys[key], T, KeyName>];
}[keyof Keys]

type Option = {
    label: string,
    id: Country
}

const data: ExhaustiveArrayOfObjects<MapOfKeysOf<Country>, Option, "id"> = [
    {
        label: "United Kingdom",
        id: 'uk',
    },
    {
        label: "France",
        id: 'france',
    },
    {
        label: "India",
        id: 'india',
    }
]

const option: Option = data[0]
```

You can check more on [this playgroud](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gVwHbAE4igXigIgQaxygB9cAzVAQyQGMIjScBLJAEycpwG4BYAKH6hIUALKUwAeTIBpCCADOUgDwBVKBAAewCG3lR5aFgHMAfFigBvflBtQA2vjlQWUFQF0AXKPFTZC5QCiGjQANgisEKoANFCOICYmvHwAvvyC4NBBABaUCAZMAG4QAIKoVCBSEgBGAFYQNMDySn56mtq6lg5yXgaoxp6WyckxACrmFsNQfgBylAC20G06rHq9xuY4BZRh9GbYE%20pay3otUAD89m5QXlZ8tvZxzkixcnBkU3LyA49LHWtIRnO9jGADIoAAlepwVCsZpyWYLGJxEwxAB06OyuXyRVK5UqtXqjThCi6IDcoxiM3mEBMVy8djcSWSpLeHwUbjSfCE0AkYGATDgz321lsIUoVQgIR6hgBURFNiYrC88GQaBA-FSAj4NEFBigrEowEoXkxeX5OLKlAqZGqdQaTTEkhkn2UKpQ6BRUF5-MFMWYrBwe3s8ssIfuYolUtwKiQTG0rCmxlYcDmODld3utkVXgA5AQc%20n7sMQ7dM6LxZKvDgAGJUWj0Qtl5xKqA5ijUOgFkPFjM2UtNiOV3AASTYHDTYazLZzLHYlC7vagmo5Wp1SD1cD5AqQXm92-MBqNdgADG4gA)

Answer (score 0):

I am using some utility functions from a library but the it is total achievable without using one. I actually got some help from stack overflow in order to come up with this solution haha... Credits to [caTS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18244921/cats) [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74042748/typescript-recursive-type-function-returns-never-incorrectly)

```js
import { List, Union } from "ts-toolbelt";

type GetData<TCountries extends string[]> = List.Length<TCountries> extends 0
  ? []
  : List.Append<GetData<List.Pop<TCountries>>, {
    value: List.Last<TCountries>
  }>;

export const data : GetData<Union.ListOf<Country>> = [
  {value: "uk"},
  {value: "france"},
  // how to make typescript complain here that I forgot to add {value: "india"}?
];
```

Comment: This is fragile. `ListOf` does not preserve the pseudo-ordering of the source union. It simply appears to work. Randomly, some day, the ordering of the output tuple will change and the same code will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's ugly, but it's not factorial complexity and it does not require a helper function.

```js
type Country = "uk" | "france" | "india";

const data = [
    { value: 'uk' },
    { value: 'france' },
    { value: 'india' }
] as const;

type test = IsExhaustive<typeof data>

type IsExhaustive<
    T extends Country extends Values ? unknown : { error: [Country, 'does not extend', Values] },
    Values =  keyof {
        [K in keyof T as T[K] extends {value: PropertyKey} ? T[K]['value'] : never]: never
    }
> = T
```