# Typescript recursive type function returns "never" incorrectly

Tags: typescript

I believe this type function is not evaluating to the correct type. Is this so?

```js
import { List, Union } from "ts-toolbelt";

type Wow<TArr extends string[]> = TArr['length'] extends 0
  ? {}
  : {
    value: List.Last<TArr>
  } & Wow<List.Pop<TArr>>;

// eval to never, because Wow<List.Pop<TArr>> returns never
// when the list have a single element left
type a = Wow<['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']>;
```

Comment: "Is there something Typescript cannot do?" is an overly-broad question, whose broad answer is "Yes, there are thousands of open [issues in GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) which talk about things TypeScript cannot do."  If you want to make your question more specific, by asking about one of your two scenarios ([just one, please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)) then it can possibly be answered, but you should [edit] the question and title to be obviously focused on the particular issue.

Comment: Turing completeness has a very specific, mathematical definition regarding the kinds of algorithms that can or cannot be computed by a system. I think you're misunderstanding it to mean hand-wavy term for "can express everything conveniently, unambiguously and clearly in a statically provable type system", which it's simple not. [To make it worse, every non-trivial formal system is either incomplete (there are things it can't prove) or inconsistent (it cant prove its consistency).](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Gödel's_incompleteness_theorems) Type systems are no different.

Comment: @jcalz ok will do

Comment: What you want to achieve ?

Comment: You are intersecting `{ value: ... }` with another `{ value: ... }`. If the two types in both `value` properties don't match then you get `{ value: never }`.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've voted to reopen the question now that it's more focused.

Comment: @caTS ah I see Do you mind just posting it as an answer?

Comment: You said you get `never`, so does that mean you get `{ value: never }`, or does the whole type get simplified to `never`?

Comment: @caTS The whole thing evaluates to never